# How Many Combinations of $3$ zeros and $2$ ones

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm rusty on combinations and permutations. I'm dealing with groups of binary numbers.

> Each group is five digits long, and they all have $2$ "$1$'s" and $3$ "$0$'s". Ex: "$10100$". I'm trying to find the number of possible combinations. Would this be $5c2$? Or a permutation?

Comment: There aren't that many of those, why don't you list them all and see for yourself?

Comment: @dtldarek Well, now I know what to do when there are more digits, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you allow $0$'s in the first digits, then the possible combinations are $\binom{5}{2} = 10$, as you choose $2$ "places" in which you will put the $1$.

If you don't want $0$ as first digit, then it is like fixing the first digito to be $1$ and then choosing a place among the $4$ remaining to put the other $1$, so you have $\binom{4}{1} = 4$ possibilities.

Comment: Yeah, 0s and 1s can be in either digit as long as each has exactly 3 and 2, respectively

Comment: @Marla Then the first line is the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

$5C2$

$ = \displaystyle\frac{5!}{3! \times 2! } = 10  $

Comment: why negative vote ? Pls clarify .

Comment: This answer is correct if you allow $0$´s in the first digits, I didn´t vote negative, I need a clarification too.

Comment: Yes binaries can have 0's in the first digit .That's why I gave this answer and I was the first to give this answer . But really vexed .

Comment: If the OP wanted a numeric count, you could have just posted $10$. So you clearly understand that he wants an explanation, yet there is none here. He asks "Is it 5C2," for example, and then you give him the formula for $5C2$ without noting that, yes, it *is* $5C2$. Being fast is only worthwhile when you take the time to consider the kind of help the OP wants. Sometimes an answer can be bad even when technically correct.

Comment: Yes what I did was keeping in mind the formula . if n object are there and in which p are of one kind , q are of another kind . so $ \displaystyle\frac{5!}{3! \times 2!}$. Thats why I wrote it that way . Ok lesson learnt. "Answer to the point". Thanks